# Create Icon in notification area

Tags: c++, service, icons

Is there a possibility to create ICON in notification area in C++ other that using System.Windows.Forms::NotifyIcon class.

I would like to enable a Service to display the Icon.

Thanks
Moti

Comment: I don't know if it fits under the same category as the .NET way, but `Shell_NotifyIcon` with `NIM_ADD`.

Comment: If it's a Windows Service, it is not supposed to interact with user directly.

Comment: Having a service display an icon won't work in newer versions of Windows, but even if it did it's a *horrible* idea to begin with. If you absolutely need a tray icon, then write an app that runs in the user's context that creates a notification icon, and have *it* talk to the service.

Comment: @Nik Why wouldn't it work in newer versions of windows? The only thing you need to show an icon in the traybar afaik is a window and creating invisible windows should work fine for services too.

Comment: Services cannot interact with the desktop in newer versions of Windows. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. Good to know I assume.

Comment: Thanks All, I got your recommendation and will create app to manage the icons and not from the services.